# how to change \n to <br> using java script for a textbox

Tags: forms, textbox, line-breaks

my textbox output always has one line , even if i press enter the output is always one line,

ex:
user input:

```
Name: Stack
Last: Over
Address: Flow
```

unwanted output:

```
Name: Stack Last: Over Address: Flow
```

is there anyway to allow multiple lines in a textbox

the output should also be:

```
Name: Stack
Last: Over
Address: Flow
```

the output is sent to my php script. any javascript or php script is fine as long as 
the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

By textbox output do you mean the value you get out of that textbox? HTML textboxes do not support multi-line input, you should use textarea instead. This is of course, the pure HTML approach.

I am only familiar with ASP.NET, but there, you would use a TextBox with TextMode="Multiline".

If by output you mean you have a string with **\n** and you want to replace that with **< br/>**, you could implement a javascript function to do that for you, like:

```
function ToHtmlLineBreaks(output)
{
    return output.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br/>");
}
```

To display it on a html page you still need to use something other that textbox, for the line breaks to show properly.